# VSCode wrappingColumn setting not working with file from linux server

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode (windows) to open a file from a linux server, with LF newlines.  VSCode recognizes that the file uses LF newlines, but the wrappingColumn setting does not seem to affect it, it wraps at the editor's edge no matter what the setting is.  The setting DOES affect any document I create in VSCode, even with newlines set to LF.  Anyone know what's going on here?  I was hoping VSCode might be a good replacement for Wordpad for opening these files.  I also found if I copy/paste from the file into a new file, it continues to wrap, ignoring wrappingColumn.  Could there be something else amiss besides LF versus CRLF?

Edit:

My issue is that the wrappingColumn setting is not affecting a certain file.  Any files I create myself are affected properly.  I used a setting of 10 to make it obvious whether it was responding to the setting or not.  The only difference I'm aware of is that the offending file was created on a Linux server.  At first I thought this was similar to the issue where Notepad doesn't recognize Unix style newlines, but I don't think it could be since VSCode clearly recognizes both LF and CRLF.  Other than that, I'm not sure what is special about this file.

Edit again!

I experimented more, don't think the linux file is special anymore.  It appears that there are some circumstances where having a line that is at least 300 characters long MIGHT cause wrappingColumn setting to be ignored.  That is my impression at this time.  I was able to reproduce it consistently as long as I only one or two lines, and if either one is at least 300 characters the setting is ignored.  Adding in more lines, there were times when having some lines >= 300 did not cause the issue, but I couldn't find the pattern (if there is one).

Comment: The wrapping in VSCode is completely independent of the line ending. Can you please share the settings.json that you're using

Comment: "editor.wrappingColumn": 0 is the only one I used.  For my test to see whether it was affecting it or not, I changed it to 10 to be super obvious.This is in my Workspace settings, in case that matters.  It seems to insist on wrapping this file at the edge of the editor (but row numbers are still accurate, so I don't get the impression it's ignoring newlines).

Answer (score 9):

As a workaround, setting `"editor.wrappingColumn": -1` completely disables wrapping.

Comment: This, -1, is the only value that seems to have any effect at all. Luckily it's all I wanted. Every integer I tried just caused the line to wrap at the viewport but -1 actually works.

Answer (score 1):

`editor.wrappingColumn` can be set to `0` to enable viewport wrapping (i.e. not get a horizontal scrollbar):

[image: wrapping column set to 0]

You can force wrapping at a certain column. E.g. Change it to something like `10`:

[image: wrapping column set to 10]

In any case, the .json file must be valid JSON after stripping comments. Look out for trailing commas...